# Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource 22

Tags: php, mysql

I don't understand why I am getting this error:

> Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL
>   result resource

My code is:

```
$alreadyMember = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT id FROM members WHERE emailAddress='{$_SESSION['register']['email']}'"));
```

I am also getting the error here:

```
$alreadyRegistered = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT confirm_code FROM memberstemp WHERE emailAddress='{$_SESSION['register']['email']}'"));
```

Comment: `mysql_query("SELECT id FROM members WHERE emailAddress = '{$_SESSION['register']['email']}'") or die(mysql_error());`, what does it return? And what is the value of the `$_SESSION`?

Comment: try storing the $_SESSION['register']['email'] in a variable and use that in the query.

Comment: `emailAdress` is an array of `string`s? Then I would recommend to rename it to `emailAdresses`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `mysql_query()` fails, it returns `FALSE` instead of a MySQL result resource.

So basically `mysql_query()` is failing and you are passing `FALSE` to `mysql_fetch_assoc()` instead of the resource you are supposed to.

You have to run `mysql_query()` separately and check if it returns `FALSE` before proceeding, in which case you print `mysql_error()` to learn what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It is best to separate query and the fetching of result for easier debugging and prevent unnecessary error, like:

```
 $query = "SELECT id FROM members WHERE emailAddress='{$_SESSION['register']['email']}'";
 $result = mysql_query($query) or die("Error : ".mysql_error.__LINE__);
 if ($result) // Test if result has no error
    {
      $alreadyMember = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    }
```

However, it is highly recommended to use prepared statements using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) to prevent [sql injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) instead of simple `mysql()` extensions.